# Space between fields - Netsuite Addres Form

Tags: forms, templates, netsuite, space

I have created a new customized address form in Netsuite (for France), but in the pdf template, I have postcode and city next to each other (please see the picture attached).
Can you please advise how I can add space between them.

Thank you in advance,

Best regards
Rado

[image]

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you customize the address form, there is a section on the top right called "Address Template". Make sure that there is a space there between the `<ZIP>` and `<STATE>`.

[image]